# Use Spring WebMVC application as jar file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jar, war

We have spring based webMVC project where we have defined controller, service and DAO classes. We have to re-use the DAO classes to implement Task Manager. 
(How to schedule and what product to use is not yet decided, any help on this is also very helpful).

I am planning to add a main class and invoke a method from main class in Service or Impl classes.

So, my question is

1. Is my approach correct?
2. Is there any other way to execute this?

Answer (score 0):

The optimal way to do this would be to extract the "common" code to another module which would be a jar, then depend on it with a third project that is the command line one. This would be easiest if you are using maven or gradle for managing your projects. You would end up with:

- root

  - lib (jar project)
  - war (current project)
  - commandline jar

If using maven / gradle you can also have a manifest file generated for you with the appropriate main class defined.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot does that thing. So, one way could be to create a very simple Spring Boot starter project either by visiting [start.spring.io](http://start.spring.io/) or using the *Spring Starter Project Wizard* of STS, and exploring the generated source to get an idea of how it is done. Better yet, you could ponder if your project could be migrated to Spring Boot.